# Problem with heanet.ie when trying to download gpg keys

Tags: security, gnupg, debian

Having an issue trying to download gpg security keys from heanet.ie servers on my debian/linux distro when trying to install mariadb as the keys are not signed. Anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and *official* flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.

Answer (score 0):

So I've been on to Heanet.ie and got some help from one of their very helpful staff. It turns out Heanet don't sign their keys but the issue can be resolved using this command:
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys F1656F24C74CD1D8
and then
sudo apt-get update

With adv --recv-key you can download key from keyservers directly into the trusted set of keys.
   Note:There are no security checks performed with this command so it is used completely at the users own risk.  I hope this helps anyone facing the same issue.